# remove li element from html entirely

Tags: jquery, html

I have an HTML list like below, im trying to remove all the li's from it, entirely. I'm using Jquery to achieve this effect. However it's not having the effect I desired, it's not actually removing the li from the DOM it's just setting it's display state to hidden:

```
<li style="display: none;"> </li>
```

### Jquery

```
 var size = parseInt($(".thumbs li").size(),10);
 for( var i=0; i< size; i++) {
    var src = $('.thumbs li:nth-child('+i+')').remove();    
 }
```

### HTML

```
<ul class="thumbs noscript">
 <li>
  <a class="thumb" name="leaf" href="" title="Title #0">
     <img src="" alt="Title #0"/>
  </a>
  <div class="caption">
     <div class="download">
        <a href="">Download Original</a>
     </div>
     <div class="image-title">Title #0</div>
     <div class="image-desc">Description</div>
  </div>
 </li>
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you just do `$('.thumbs li').remove()`?

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".thumbs li").remove();
```

You don't need that loop. (But just for clarification, your problem in the loop is that you're removing elements as you go, so halfway through, nth child elements no longer exist in the DOM)

Comment: `$(".thumbs").html('')` is what I would do, but yours is the right way.